# How to avoid Xcode Bot from integrating after an automated commit incrementing the build number

Tags: xcode, cocoa, version, build-process, bots

My project's scheme has a Pre-action and Post-action script for Archive.  In the pre-action script, the build number is incremented and in the post-action script the new build number gets committed.  In the Xcode bot's configuration, the bot is scheduled to start an integration for "On Commit". What happens is that the build number commit causes the bot to start an integration after the current integration has finished, thereby continuously building/integrating into an infinite loop.

I want to be able to run the integrations only when the developers commit new code and not when bot increments build/version number. How can I do this?  Is there a way to do this push before the bot gets the source code/commit information?